# Prove that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial having real coefficients such that $F(x) = f(x^3) + xg(x^3)$ and $F(x)$ is divisible by $x^2 + x + 1$.

Tags: polynomials

Prove that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial having real coefficients such that $F(x) = f(x^3) + xg(x^3)$ and $F(x)$ is divisible by $x^2 + x + 1$. Prove that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are divisible by $x - 1$. I tried approaching this question using remainder theorem and replacement properties of function but couldn't proceed. Is this the correct approach or is there some other approach?

Comment: What about $g$? Does it have real coefficients?

Comment: @tattwamasi It doesn't matter - see my answer.

Comment: yes 'g' also has real coefficients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\quad &x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1\mid f(\color{#c00}{x^3})+xg(\color{#c00}{x^3})\\[.3em]
\iff\ & x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1\mid f(\color{#c00}1)\ +\ xg(\color{#c00}1)\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \ \color{#c00}{x^3\equiv 1}\!\!\pmod{x^2+x+1}\\[.3em]
\iff\ & f(1) = 0 = g(1)\\[.3em]
\iff\ &x\!-\!1\mid f,g
\end{align}$

Comment: **Remark** $ $ The proof works over any commutative ring, not only $\Bbb R\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x) = (x-1) p(x) + A$ and $g(x) = (x-1)q(x)+B$ with $A,\,B\in\Bbb{R}$. (That is, write explicitly the division of $f$ and $g$ by $x-1$.) Substitute in the equation for F. Since $x^2+x+1$ divides F and $x^3-1$, you find that $x^2+x+1$ divides $A+Bx$, and therefore $A=B=0$.

Comment: Same as my answer, but without the modular language.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the roots of $x^2+x+1$ are
$$x_1=\frac{-1+ i\sqrt{3}}{2}\qquad x_2=\frac{-1- i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
and $x_1^3=x_2^3=1$. Thus
$$\begin{aligned}
F(x_1)=f(x_1^3)+x_1g(x_1^3)=f(1)+x_1g(1)=0 \\
F(x_2)=f(x_2^3)+x_2g(x_2^3)=f(1)+x_2g(1)=0
\end{aligned}$$
Now manipulate these two equations to see what you can say about $f(1)$, $g(1)$.